# Creating "columns" inside a DIV: how to place them?

Tags: css, html

Here it is: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

In the section "O que fazemos", I need to create two "columns", the left side will show the text and the right side will show the image. How am I supposed to place the image correctly?

Also, in another section, I will need to create three "columns". Do I follow the same rules?

Keep in mind that I want the text to be aligned on the left and the image on the right.

Thanks a lot.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>bask.ra</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- COMECO DO NIVO SLIDER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- FIM DO NIVO SLIDER -->

<!-- COMECO DO MENU FIXO -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('.menu-fundo');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            nav.addClass("f-menu");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-menu");
        }
    });

});
</script>
<!-- FIM DO MENU FIXO -->

</head>

<body>

<div class="menu-fundo">
<div class="menu">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>

<div class="logo">

<img src="images/logo.png" />

</div>

        <ul id="menutop">
              <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#equipe">EQUIPE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#quem">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#como">COMO FAZEMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#que">O QUE FAZEMOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
$("#menutop a").click(function(){
   var menuid = $(this).attr("href");
   $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuid).offset().top - $('.menu').height() }, "slow");
   return false;
});
</script>

<div class="elementos">

<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="images/slide1.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide2.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide3.png"/>
</div>



<div class="o-que-fazemos">
  <a id="que"></a>
  <h1 class="o-que-fazemos-title">O QUE FAZEMOS?</h1>
 <h1 class="o-que-fazemos-subtitle">COMUNICAÇÃO + DESIGN</h1>


<div class="o-que-fazemos-content-1">

<b>SUA MARCA VAI ALÉM.</b><br />
<br />

<b><i>Consolidar uma marca vai além.</i></b><br />
<br />

Além de um simples nome, razão ou
definição, consolidar uma marca depende
de uma experiência. E é a partir disto que
as ideias surgem. Um novo conceito e uma
nova definição de negócio.<br />

A <b>BASK.RA</b> nasceu para pensar, criar e
gerenciar o posicionamento da sua
empresa no mercado.

</div>


<div class="o-que-fazemos-content-2">

<img src="images/oqfazemos.png" />

</div>



</div>

<div class="como-fazemos">
  <a id="como"></a>
  <h1 class="como-fazemos-title">COMO FAZEMOS?</h1>

<p align="center"><img src="images/comofazemos.png" /></p>

</div>

<div class="quem-somos">
  <a id="quem"></a>
  QUEM SOMOS?<br />
<br />

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

<div class="a-equipe">
  <a id="equipe"></a>
  EQUIPE<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

<div class="o-contato">
  <a id="contato"></a>
  CONTATO<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


html,body {
    height:100%;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    }

div {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }

.login {
  display: table-cell;
}

logo {  
    border:0;
    z-index:9999;
    float:left;

    }

.menu-fundo {
    background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:fixed;
    }

.f-menu {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    } /* isso vai fazer o menu ficar fixo no topo */

.menu {
height: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 9999;
background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
position:fixed; width:100%
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    }

.menu ul li {
float: right;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:0px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    }

.menu ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:3px solid #999;
    }

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-top:3px solid #EA0000;
    }

.o-que-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/oqfazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.o-que-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffc709;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.o-que-fazemos-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }


.o-que-fazemos-content-1 {  
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 30%;
    }


.o-que-fazemos-content-2 {  
    margin-right:10%;
    width: 50%;

    }

.como-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/comofazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.como-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.quem-somos {
    background-image: url('images/quemsomosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.a-equipe {
    background-image: url('images/EQUIPE-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.o-contato {
    background-image: url('images/contato-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.banner li {
    list-style: none;
    }

.banner ul li {
    float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   @charset "utf-8";
```

/* CSS Document */

```
html,body {
    height:100%;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    }

div {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }

.login {
  display: table-cell;
}

logo {  
    border:0;
    z-index:9999;
    float:left;

    }

.menu-fundo {
    background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:fixed;
    }

.f-menu {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    } /* isso vai fazer o menu ficar fixo no topo */

.menu {
height: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 9999;
background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
position:fixed; width:100%
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    }

.menu ul li {
float: right;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:0px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    }

.menu ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:3px solid #999;
    }

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-top:3px solid #EA0000;
    }
/*your grid*/
.row, .o-que-fazemos, .como-fazemos, .quem-somos {
display: block;
float: left;
postiion: relative;
overflowhidden;
}

.o-que-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/oqfazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;

}
.o-que-fazemos-content-1, .o-que-fazemos-content-2 {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 }

.o-que-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffc709;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.o-que-fazemos-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
.o-que-fazemos-content-1 {  
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align: left;
    }


.o-que-fazemos-content-2 {  

    text-align: right;
    }

.como-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/comofazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.como-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.quem-somos {
    background-image: url('images/quemsomosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.a-equipe {
    background-image: url('images/EQUIPE-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.o-contato {
    background-image: url('images/contato-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.banner li {
    list-style: none;
    }

.banner ul li {
    float: left;
    }
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something really wrong. Check this out: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html. I just want to be able to use my header navigation and create as many "columns" as I want inside the DIVs section. =/

Comment: dont forget opening and closing .row for each section.

Comment: Now it looks better! Just one more question: what happened to "Como Fazemos" section now?

Comment: didn't surround the section with .row

Comment: What am I missing? : http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html / http://baskra.com/teste/style.css

Comment: try adding width: 100%; min-width: 100%; to como fazemos class

Comment: Didn't work. I wonder why this is happening only with this DIV. I haven't done anything different (as far as I can remember).

Comment: try surrounding your image in an como-fazemos content div as in your above rows.  this may push your image to fill more of the center of your screen.

Comment: Not working. I really appreciate all your help so far. I don't know what else I could try.

Comment: i just checked your status and it looks like you have it fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Make your sections into a grid to more easily align your columns.  for exemple

```
.o-que-fazemos {
**postion: relative;**
**display: block;**
**float: left;**
overflow: hidden; *ie7 bug fix*
}

.o-que-fazemos-content-1, .o-que-fazemos-content-2 {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 }

.o-que-fazemos-content-1  {
text-align: left;
}

.o-que-fazemos-content-2 {
text-align: right;
}
```

Follow the same method for your other columns. 
Everything needs to keep the float or it won't keep its height.

A list apart has an excellent article on this topic.
http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: It's working, but for some reason it "breaks" my next page "Como fazemos". When I click on the link, it doesn't work and it also "cuts" a bit of the top.

Comment: try enclosing each of your sections into a .row div

Comment: .o-que-fazemos, .row {
     **postion: relative;**
     **display: block;**
     **float: left;**
     overflow: hidden; *ie7 bug fix*

Comment: Which DIVs? Only the main DIVs, like .o-que-fazemos, .como-fazemos, .quem-somos or .o-que-fazemos-content-1 and content-2 too? All I have to do is add .row after the name?

Comment: Just your main sections

Comment: .row, o-que-fazemos,  .row, .como-fazemos,  etc

Comment: Didn't work. When I click Como Fazemos, it takes me to O Que Fazemos section. I don't understand how it can be affected by what you taught me.

Comment: take a look at getbootstrap.com for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up on how divs behave and the way css float works: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Try adding float: left; to your second content div, i.e:

```
.o-que-fazemos-content-2 {  
    margin-right:10%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Edit: And, as Josh pointed you might need to clear the floats as well, i.e add overflow: hidden on .o-que-fazemos or use a clear fix

Comment: It works, but for some reason it "breaks" the DIV. Check out live. Do you know why? Also, how can I make content-1 and content-2 vertically aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding **overflow: hidden;** to:

```
.o-que-fazemos {
background-image: url('images/oqfazemosFUNDO.png');
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
height:auto;
font-size:28px;
padding: 50px;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try putting a div around o-que-fazemos-content-1 and 2, and place the overflow: hidden; style there instead.

Comment: I've tried both, but nothing happened. Thanks anyway!